# gradle jcenter alternative or mirror

Tags: java, spring, maven, gradle, repository

My server can't connect to jcenter (amazon cloud).
Can I specify alternative jcenter-server ?

> 20:23:17          :microservice-wrapper:unspecified >
>   org.akhikhl.gretty:gretty:2.0.0 20:23:17       > Could not resolve
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-loader-tools:1.5.4.RELEASE.
>   20:23:17          > Could not get resource
>   'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-loader-tools/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-loader-tools-1.5.4.RELEASE.pom'.
>   20:23:17             > Could not HEAD
>   'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-loader-tools/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-loader-tools-1.5.4.RELEASE.pom'.
>   20:23:17                > Connect to repo.jfrog.org:443
>   [repo.jfrog.org/34.227.55.218, repo.jfrog.org/34.200.155.151] failed:
>   Connection refused (Connection refused) 20:23:17    > Could not
>   resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:1.3.3.RELEASE.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can configure custom repositories as described in the [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:declaring_custom_repository) documentation. Keep in mind jcenter is maven repository type. If you want to provide a custom maven repository you can define its URL the following way:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://repo.mycompany.com/maven2"
    }
}
```

Alternatives to jcenter are described in the [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/repository_types.html#sub:maven_central) documentation as well, like: `mavenCentral()`. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40544114/9647266) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40390270/9647266) similar answers illustrates how to achieve the expected behavior.

Comment: I have no my own repo. And I haven't found alternative url.

Comment: You should always mark a helpful answer as the solution, if it was helpful, or provide a solution yourself to avoid having dead threads or solved-unsolved questions in StackOverflow.